# Find indicated projection: The projection of $[1,2,1]$ on the plane $x + y + z= 0$ in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Find indicated projection: The projection of $[1,2,1]$ on the plane $x + y + z= 0$ in $\mathbb R^3$

Solution: Taking y = 0, and z = 0, we have $a = [1,0,-1]$ and $b = [1,-1,0]$

Then using $c = [1,1,1]$

\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   0 & -1 & 1 & 2\\
   -1 & 0 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}

which has a solution $[-1/3,2/3,-1/3]$

--

I don't get how they got a, b. Could someone explain please

Comment: Pretty much as the solution says: set $y=0$ in the equation of the plane and come up with values for $x$ and $z$ that satisfy it, and similarly for $z=0$. That aside, there’s a much easier way to solve this problem than the given method.

Comment: What does it mean to set y = 0? $x + 0 + z = 0$, then the solution for a would be $a = [-1, 0, 1]$, right? Confused

Comment: Plug $0$ in for $y$ in the equation, reducing it to $x=-z$. Any vector that satisfies this will do for $a$.

Comment: They got, $a = [1,0,-1], [1,-1,0]$ for a,b respectively. I got $[-1,0,1], [-1,1,0]$. Both give different answers

Comment: No, they produce the same answer. However, the solution that you cite is incorrect: it should be $[-1/3,2/3,4/3]$. There might be a typo, or you might be misreading $4/3$ as $-1/3$ (likely if it’s a poor copy).